# How to configure node.js module on localhost

Tags: 7, nodejs

I am trying to setup [node.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs) module on my localhost environment. I have tried different configurations but still not found correct way to make it work. In my log messages I get:

[image]

[image]

nodejs.config.js

```
    backendSettings = {
  "scheme":"http",
  "host":"localhost",
  "port":8080,
  "key":"/path/to/key/file",
  "cert":"/path/to/cert/file",
  "resource":"node_modules/socket.io",
  "publishUrl":"publish",
  "serviceKey":"",
  "backend":{
  "port":80,
  "host":"localhost",
  "messagePath":"/drupal738/nodejs/message"},
  "clientsCanWriteToChannels":false,
  "clientsCanWriteToClients":false,
  "extensions":"",
  "debug":true,
  "transports":["websocket",
  "flashsocket",
  "htmlfile",
  "xhr-polling",
  "jsonp-polling"],
  "jsMinification":true,
  "jsEtag":true,
  "logLevel":1};
```

server.js

```
var channels = {},
authenticatedClients = {},
sockets = {},
onlineUsers = {},
presenceTimeoutIds = {},
contentChannelTimeoutIds = {},
tokenChannels = {},
settingsDefaults = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost',
  resource: '/node_modules/socket.io',
  serviceKey: '',
  debug: false,
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  publishUrl: 'publish',
  kickUserUrl: 'user/kick/:uid',
  logoutUserUrl: 'user/logout/:authtoken',
  addUserToChannelUrl: 'user/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
  removeUserFromChannelUrl: 'user/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
  addChannelUrl: 'channel/add/:channel',
  checkChannelUrl: 'channel/check/:channel',
  removeChannelUrl: 'channel/remove/:channel',
  setUserPresenceListUrl: 'user/presence-list/:uid/:uidList',
  addAuthTokenToChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
  removeAuthTokenFromChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
  toggleDebugUrl: 'debug/toggle',
  contentTokenUrl: 'content/token',
  publishMessageToContentChannelUrl: 'content/token/message',
  getContentTokenUsersUrl: 'content/token/users',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket','polling', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  backend: {
    host: 'localhost',
    scheme: 'http',
    port: 80,
    basePath: '/',
    strictSSL: false,
    messagePath: 'nodejs/message',
    httpAuth: ''
  },
  logLevel: 1
},
extensions = [];
```

I am using **WAMP** and I have installed **node.js** on my system and required packages(connect, express, request, socket.io,) in my `sites/all/modules/contrib/nodejs` directory.

Comment: OK, but what's actually wrong about these configs? What's the problem? Why do you think it isn't "proper"?

Comment: Is my resource path settings correct ? Do I require service Key ? When I broadcast a message, no message gets appeared.

Comment: also I donot get message like "info - socket.io started" when I start node.js server using command "node service.js"